# Difference between using % and getting the least significant bit for odd/even

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit

I've been wondering, what is the difference in using `%` and getting the the least significant bit of a number to know whether is odd or even.

using `%` would be something like

- `n % 2 == 0` In this case `n` is an even number
- `n % 2 == 1` In this case `n` is an odd number

Using the least significant bit

- `n & 1 == 0` In this case `n` is an even number
- `n & 1 == 1` In this case `n` is an odd number

Is using `%` faster that the least significant bit of a number?

Comment: *"Is using % faster that the least significant bit of a number?"* You can find that out by writing a simple benchmark for it. Performance can vary by implementation.

Comment: Here's a jsPerf test case: https://jsperf.com/modulus-vs-least-significant-bit

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox had about the same speed for both, while on Chrome the bitmask was about 20% faster.  So it comes down to how well optimized the JS compiler is in a particular browser.

Comment: The difference between these two is a negligible [microoptimization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). Unless you're evaluating the statement tens of millions of times, it will have no effect on the end-user,

Comment: `3.3 & 1` is 1, `3.3 % 2` is 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside a possible speed difference, the use of bitwise operators changes the number to a 32 bit number, where as a number has 64 bit for a floating point number.

The use of larger numbers is limited:

```
            32 bit                   64 bit
----  -------------  --------------------------------------------
min    -2147483648    -9007199254740991   Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
max     2147483647     9007199254740991   Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

Comment: Safe integers aren't the full 64 bits though. After 2^51, you'll only have even numbers

Comment: @Bergi is almost correct. 64-bit IEEE floating-point numbers have 53 bits of fraction (mantissa).